# Waiting before passport control in Düsseldorf airport

Tags: schengen, passport-stamps, dusseldorf

From Leeds, England I'm due to arrive at Düsseldorf, Germany on the 23rd at 8:30pm.

Is it possible to sit out and wait before passport control in Düsseldorf until 12am? The intention being to get an entry stamp for the following day (24th) to extend my Schengen area due date

Comment: I cant seem to find the flight your talking about in DUS

Comment: Some facilities have to operate until some time after the last flight but AB6145 is a domestic flight and DUS is [not set up for overnight airside transit](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) so I am not sure the non-Schengen terminal or passport check will still be open at midnight.

Comment: OTOH, there are a few non-Schengen flights (London, Istanbul…) around 10 PM.

Comment: Thanks relaxed, sadly i dont think passport control would be open 2 hours after the arrival of a flight. It would be nice to be sure if that is the case

Comment: If waiting in Amsterdam is an option, I recommend doing that. It's opened 24/7 and has a large airside concourse where departing and arriving passengers are not separated and it's easy to wait comfortably (with restaurants, rest areas, even a museum).

Answer (score 2):

After arriving in the Schengen zone from the UK, you want to wait until after midnight to have your passport stamped.  The extra day of unspent leave will allow you follow through with other reservations you have made.

Yes, this is possible if another Schengen arrival flight is arriving closer to midnight. In other words, you cannot just show up at the immigration desk in a deserted terminal. You need to clear immigration in a 'cluster' of people who have arrived.

As for the air side waiting time, appropriate dress and grooming is essential. Remember that the Grenzpolizei have the right to challenge anyone near a border, even if the person is waiting.

Your strategy is mildly abusive, but it's legal and will certainly work if a few caveats are observed.